# I cant show content of control in canvas control, but image is showed

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, binding, contentcontrol

```
<Grid x:Name="grdTouchZoom"  RenderTransform="1 0 0 1 0 0" IsManipulationEnabled="True" Background="Transparent">            
            <Grid Background="Transparent"/>
            <Canvas>                               
                <Image Name="img" Source="c:/1.jpg" />
                <ContentControl x:Name="rt" Content="{Binding CurrentView}" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                </ContentControl>
            </Canvas>

</Grid>
```

That's my code to make slide book application. I intend use canvas object to moving my page control by changing Canvas.Left, but when I put my control which contain CurrentView object, it's not showed. I try with image control, it worked. I put my contentcontrol was out side canvas, it worked. 
Where's my wrong?

Comment: If i try to move control by changing Margin property, it move and scale down ...

Comment: Do the ContentControl have any template?

Comment: The CurrentView is a FrameworkElenment object, it will be assigned as a UserControl in run time. In my case, it contain some Storyboard objects.

Comment: Instead of `ContentControl` try with `Border`, Bind the `CurrentView` with its `Child`

Comment: I need to using binding for changeing content on runtime. I've tried with image control and it work well.

Comment: @Sankarann: I've tried as you said, but it's not worked. Here my code:
XAML:
<Border local:Attached.BindableChild="{Binding CurrentView, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"/>

MyConverter:
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value == null) return null;

            var border = new Border() { Width = 1500, Height = 1000 };
            border.Child = (FlipBookTwoSide)value;
            return border;
        }

Comment: what you did in the BindableChild changed of Attached Class?

Comment: I follow below example. 
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Binding-to-Border-Child-314d65aa

It's worked. Nice. Thank you very much Sankarann!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `ContentControl` try with `Border`, Bind the CurrentView with its `Child`